# psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn when trying to insert data into postgres database

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, dataframe

I have a pandas data framework which has data from a csv file.

I want to import that data into my postgres database.

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2

# Import CSV, create Data Frame
data = pd.read_csv('my_csv.csv', delimiter=';')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Prepare Data (Rename / Shorten Column-Headers)
columnsFromCSV = list(df.columns)
for i in columnsFromCSV:
    columnName = i.rsplit(None, 2)[0]
    df.rename(columns={i : columnName}, inplace=True)
df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()

# Connect to Database
conn = psycopg2.connect(
   database='database', user='postgres', password='admin', host='127.0.0.1', port= '5432'
)
cursor = conn.cursor() 

# Insert Data Frame into Database
for i in df.columns[1:]:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO counter (counterid) VALUES ({0})'.format(i))
    for j in range(365):
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO measurements (counterid) VALUES({0})'.format(i))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

First I want to store every counter once in the counter table and after that I want to store the daily measurements of one year in the measurements table together with the counterid, the daily measurements will be inserted at a later time.

Thats the error message I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\EnergyCounter\EnergyCounter\backend\CSV_read_script.py", line 25, in <module>
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO counter (counterid) VALUES ({0})'.format(i))
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  Column »counter1« does not exist 
LINE 1: INSERT INTO counter (counterid) VALUES (counter1)
```

Tried lower case, quoting tablenames, using "%s" instead of ".format".

Comment: Docs are there for a reason, see [Passing parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use named arguments: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

The code now looks like this and it works:

```
# Insert Data Frame into Database
for i in df.columns[1:]:
    cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO counter (counterid) VALUES (%(columnName)s)''', {'columnName': i})
    for j in range(365):
        cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO measurements (counterid) VALUES(%(columnName)s)''', {'columnName': i})
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```